# Conditionally display math formulas with variables in R Markdown

Tags: r, math, markdown, knitr

I have a problem with rendering formulas with variables in R markdown.
Here is the variables that I using (simple example):

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
series <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
count <- leng(series)
sum <- sum(series)
sum2 <- sum(series^2)
sq_formula <- TRUE
````

My problem is to print in Rmd (output = Word) math expression with knitr like:

```
$$S = \frac{\sum{S}}{n} = \frac{`r sum`}{`r count`} = `r mean(series)`$$
```

if sq_formula is FALSE, otherwise it should be:

```
$$S = \frac{\sum{S^2}}{n} = \frac{`r sum2`}{`r count`} = `r sum2 / count`$$
```

There is a way to write formulas in R chunk and print it by condition, like:

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
formula1 <- '$$ \\overline{S} = \\frac{\\sum{S}}{n} = \\frac{\\sum{`r sum`}{`r count`}}$$'
formula2 <- '$$ \\overline{S} = \\frac{\\sum{S^2}}{n} = \\frac {\\sum{`r sum2`}}{`r count`}$$'


`r if (sq_formula <- TRUE) {formula1} else {formula2}`
````

but I can't insert the variables like `r sum`, `r count` inside the chunk.
I also tried to handle the problem with `sprintf` function, but haven't found a way to insert the variables in strings in math notation. So I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the problem with `sprintf`? Can't you do

```
formula1 <- sprintf(
  '$$ \\overline{S} = \\frac{\\sum{S}}{n} = \\frac{\\sum{%s}{%s}}$$',
  sum, count
)
```

Comment: It looks like I'm not very familiar with `sprintf` function. Your example was helpful, thanks.

Wrote like this:
```
    formula1 <- sprintf(
      '$$ \\overline{S} = \\frac{\\sum{S}}{n} = \\frac{%s}{%s}$$',
      sum, counts
    )

    formula2 <- sprintf(
      '$$ \\overline{S} = \\frac{\\sum{S^2}}{n} = \\frac{%s}{%s}$$',
      sum2, counts
    )

    desc <- if (sq_formula == TRUE) {
      formula2
      } else {
        formula1
    }
```